# Stay on Remote S3 RemoteProvider

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to make snakemake read and write directly to S3. Does anyone know if it is possible to use S3RemoteProvider and have the parameter stay_on_remote=True? When I have this parameter set to True, it doesn't look like snakemake can find my inputs. I also tried to use the XRootD RemoteProvider, but it doesn't seem to be able to talk to S3. Is there another way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to set `stay_on_remote=True` on an S3RemoteProvider, but it is an uncommon usage with specific requirements.

The `stay_on_remote=True` parameter is intended for backends like XRootD where processing can be carried out remotely where the data resides: in such scenarios, a command is dispatched to the remote backend to perform some action on the data without moving the data around. This is a standard way of using XRootD systems.

In most cases, in order for Snakemake to run commands to act on S3-stored input, it is necessary to transfer the data to the machine executing the job, so `stay_on_remote` should be omitted or set to `False`. When it is `False`, Snakemake will automatically download the object, run the rule, and then delete the local copy of the object when no more jobs depend on it. If you do set `stay_on_remote=True`, that would leave the files on S3, causing any local commands to fail if they try to find or use the input--unless they can access s3 themselves.

The `S3RemoteProvider` allows `stay_on_remote=True` for the use case where you have the ability to run commands that accepts S3 pseudo-URLs for reading and writing (`s3://bucket-name/full/key/value/to/data`). This could either be a remote system, or something like samtools that accepts `s3://` locations. If `stay_on_remote=True`, the protocol will be prepended to the file automatically if it is not specified, so for the S3 provider you don't need to explicitly include `s3://` in the input file strings.

For example, `stay_on_remote=True` can be used with samtools like this:

```py
from snakemake.remote.S3 import RemoteProvider as S3RemoteProvider
S3 = S3RemoteProvider()

rule all:
    input:
        S3.remote("1000genomes/phase1/data/NA12878/exome_alignment/NA12878.mapped.illumina.mosaik.CEU.exome.20110411.bam", stay_on_remote=True)
    output:
        "out.txt"
    run:
        # samtools accepts s3:// paths, which are given when stay_on_remote=True
        shell("samtools view {input} 20:1000-100000 > {output}")
```

In the above `Snakefile`, Snakemake substitutes the input, `s3://1000genomes/phase1/[...]`, for `{input}`, and `samtools` can act on the S3 object directly.

If you include your `Snakefile` we can try to see if `stay_on_remote` would apply for what you're doing, or if there's a bug in the implementation.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will stick with the consistent option of just downloading and uploading the inputs/outputs.